# Breaking a Value List to show 5 records in one Line and then move to Next line and so on

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following code where i am tryin to use mod operator to list 5 items on the line and then move to next line, On the single line it should display 5 items and then in next line, it should display the remaining items, if the remaining items are more than 5, it should go to 3rd line then

i am trying this code: but it not doing anything

```
<cfset items = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0">
<cfif listLen(items) mod 5>
<cfoutput>
    #items##Chr(10)##chr(13)#TEST
</cfoutput> 
</cfif>
```

it is displaying all in one line

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

- You are not looping over the list to display each item.
- Chr(10) and Chr(13) (linefeed and carriage return) do not display in HTML and your browser.

I modified your code like this:

```
<cfset counter = 0>
<cfset items = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,a,b,c">
<cfloop index="thisItem" list="#items#">
    <cfset counter = counter + 1>
    <cfif counter mod 5>
        <cfoutput>#thisItem#, </cfoutput>
    <cfelse>
        <cfoutput>#thisItem#<br></cfoutput>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

[Try it here](http://trycf.com/gist/babf9cdeb54ae995a5a6f87032dfbe25/acf2016?theme=monokai)

and here is an example of that same logic using `cfscript` syntax:

```
<cfscript>
counter = 0;
items = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,a,b,c";
for (counter = 1; counter lte listlen(items); counter++) {
    if (counter mod 5) {
        writeOutput('#listGetAt(items,counter)#, ');
    } else {
        writeOutput('#listGetAt(items,counter)#<br>');
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

[Try it here](http://trycf.com/gist/430f8ad00bd10597ed3cab2d8a5fbffb/acf2016?theme=monokai)

The code I have given you here can be cleaned up a bit but hopefully it is easy to understand for you.

Comment: ok, i modified your code: `<cfset counter = 0>
<cfset items = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0">
<cfloop index="thisItem" list="#items#">
    <cfset counter = counter + 1>
    <cfif counter mod 5>
       <cfoutput>
        #thisItem# <br/>
    </cfoutput> 
    <cfelse>
    <cfoutput>
        #thisItem# 
    </cfoutput> 
    </cfif>
</cfloop>` but how do i display 1 to 5 on one line and 6to 10 on next line and remaining on 3rd line

Comment: My initial code does just that. Why did you modify it? I changed the gist back to what I had. Click the link and run it.  You will see that there are three lines. `1 2 3 4 5` on the first, `6, 7, 8, 9, 0` on the second and `a, b, c` on the third.

Comment: second gist works great but i want `12345` every item to be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

Comment: i tried using replace to insert a comma but it does not work,

Comment: Just add a comma and space to the output portion of the code. I modified the code in my answer to show you. It will not work perfectly (it will add an ending comma to lines with less than 5) but you should be able to work that out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach if you are on `CF10+`:

```
<cfscript>

    // Items List
    items_list = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,a,b,c";

    // Convert to array
    items_array = items_list.listToArray( "," );

    // Item Count
    itemCount = arrayLen( items_array );

    // Display
    for ( i = 1; i <= itemCount; i += 5) {
        writeOutput( items_array.slice( i, i + 5 - 1 > itemCount ? itemCount % 5 : 5 ).toList( "," ) & "<br>" );
    }
</cfscript>
```

Here is the [`TryCF`](http://trycf.com/gist/d8aca4c9d2675cdafe0a435d450bcc8a/acf2016?theme=monokai).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.

```
<cfset items = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,a,b,c">
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#listLen(items)#" index="i">
        #listGetAt(items,i)#
        <cfif i mod 5 eq 0>
            <br>
        <cfelseif i neq listLen(items)>
            ,
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Results in

```
1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 
6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 0 
a , b , c
```